# String mash (recursion) C++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment that asks me to do the following task:
"Have a user input a string. Then display this string smashed up as follows: display the first character in the string, then the last, then the second, then the second to last, then the third... So if the string is “abcdef”, it will display:
afbecd (input “abcdef”)"
Here is my approach, but it did not run. I got a Segmentation Fault 11.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

void printLetters(string s);

int main()
{
  string sequence;
  cout << "Enter a sequence: ";
  getline(cin, sequence);
  printLetters(sequence);
}

void printLetters(string s)
{
  int a = floor(s.length()/2.0);
  // stopping case
  if(s == "")
  {
    return;
  }

  // reduce problem
  printLetters(s.substr(0)); 
  //cout << s[0];
  cout << s[a];
}
```

Here is an exmaple: 12345. In my function printLetters(string s), I print out the string starting at index 0, then I have the full string 12345. Then, I "cout" the content at index s.length()/2, which is the middle character "3". Then go back to the string and keep printing out the substring starting at index 0 again but this time, it is 1245. I keep repeating the steps until I get 1. In the lecture, my professor explained when the recursion reaches the end of the process, it will go back up from the bottom back to the top. Then when I reach 1, it will go back up to 5, 2, 3,4. So I assume I would print out the string "15234", but I did not. If you have any idea, I would be happy to listen. Thanks a lot!

Here is another code which is used to reverse a string. My professor explained in class, and that was the logics he gave behind the code.

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  void printString(string s);
  int main()
  {
    printString("hello");  
    return 0;
  }
  void printString(string s)
  {
      if(s == "")
      {
        return;
      }   
      printString(s.substr(1));
      cout << s[0];
  }
```

Comment: `floor(s.length()/2.0)` better written as `s.length()/2`.

Comment: What do you mean, "*this time, it is 1245*". `s.substr(0)` is `s` again, i.e. `12345`.

Comment: Try to use a debugger first...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this one

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void printLetters(string s);

int main()
{
string sequence;
cout << "Enter a sequence: ";
getline(cin, sequence);
printLetters(sequence);
cout << endl;
system("pause");
}

void printLetters(string s)
{
int a =s.length();
if (a == 0)
{
    return;
}
cout << s[0];
if(a>1)
cout<< s[a - 1];
s.erase(0, 1);
a = s.length();
if(a>1)
s.erase(a-1);
printLetters(s);
}
```

Thank you so much. It works perfectly. Do you think we need system("pause")? Because I did not include it in the code and it still ran. I totally understood the logics behind your code. Thanks so much.

Comment: No it's not compulsory. It depends on which compiler you are using.